# How using git can I know "just happens push" to the master branch?

Tags: git

How using git can I know "just happens push" to the master branch?

For example to know `merge` I use `git logs --merges`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list what has just been pushed to `master`:

```
git fetch origin
git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master --name-status
```

This assume more than one commit on `master`.